# How do I add google tracking code to a wordpress.com site?

Tags: google-analytics, wordpress.com-hosting

I want to add google analytics to my free wordpress.com blog. I have the html tracking code but I can't figure out how to add it to  my blog from the wordpress.com dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

the `<script>` tag is not allowed on Wordpress.com

Since the Google Analytics script uses that tag, it's not possible to add it. This has been asked and dealt countless of times on the forums of Wordpress.com but they do not wish to compromise the security of their site by allowing scripts (Javascript/VBScript).

If you find a place to host your site and decide to use the Wordpress app (found at Wordpress.org), then you'll be able to modify it and add scripts as much as you want! That's what I ended up doing with my blog that I had originally created on Wordpress.com.

Just as an extra, I found this interesting exerpt on their forums:

> Google's rule is that only one Google
>   analytics script (Urchin) can be run
>   on any blog; they do not allow two.
>   And wordpress.com runs Google
>   analytics (urchin) on all of our
>   blogs.

source: http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/google-analytics-on-wordpress-how_

Comment: Thanks Faust, do you know how to add non-js tracking tools to wordpress.com blogs? The wordpress site tracking doesn't identify users with their inferred ip/geo-location. I just want to be able to do this. I heard there are some non-js tracking tools, which should work for wordpress.com blogs, but I do not know where I can edit the HTML in wordpress.com to add any code.

Comment: see http://onecoolsitebloggingtips.com/2009/10/24/real-time-visitor-tracking-non-javascript-for-blogs/

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that it is not supported: https://en.support.wordpress.com/stats/#additional-info

However, I would still like to know how to add some html script to my wordpress.com hosted site.